# Is it safe to just add express checkout the way paypal recommends you to?

Tags: http, security, paypal

I've never had created a web app with payments and have decided to try to make one with Paypals express checkout for my Angular App.

I'm looking over there [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/), and they suggest to throw a `<script id="paypal-checkout-script"src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>` tag and use a global **paypal** variable created from it to implement their api.

```
// will help render the paypal button in HTML when this code runs
paypal.Button.render({ ...
```

So I have a `<paypal-button>` component that will make use of this code later when the user navigates to the view with it at a later time during his session upon visiting the website.

Although I feel like something malicious could inject another script tag into the HTML and do this before my component evaluates the **paypal** object variable.

```
<script id="paypal-checkout-script" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
 <!-- another script tag below changing the paypal var --> 
 <script>
    paypal = { Button: { render: 'evil' } };
 </script>
```

I don't know much about web security but would like to clarify if doing this practice is ok?

- Should I just do http request within the app and assign it to another variable that may possibly be a global const instead?
- If I continue to do it this way will I be liable for anything, or is there a certain point, where it is no longer the apps responsibility, (e.g. the user's computer is zombified / browser is hijacked)

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated. : )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is secure. Want add more layers for extra security and/or customize the payment process?, then implement their server side solution as they state in the docs

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very secure because it is front-end. 
A more secure way is to do a server-side integration approach.